# Passing JSON object to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to pass a JSON object that looks similar to this:

```
 {"service": "AAS1", "sizeTypes":[{"id":"20HU", "value":"1.0"},{"id":"40FB","2.5"}]}
```

Just a note: In the sizeTypes, there are a total of about 58 items in the array.

When the user clicks the submit button, I need to be able to send the object to a PHP script to run an UPDATE query.  Here is the javascript that should be sending the JSON to the PHP script:

```
 $('#addNewSubmit').click(function()
 {
   var payload = {
     name: $('#addservice').val();
     sizeTypes: []
   };

   $('input.size_types[type=text]').each(function(){
     payload.sizeTypes.push({
       id: $(this).attr('id'),
       value: $(this).val()
      });
   });

   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'api/editService.php',
     data: {service: payload},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(msh){
       console.log('success');
     },
     error: function(msg){
       console.log('fail');
     }
   });
 });
```

Using the above click function, I am trying to send the object over to php script below, which is in api/editService.php:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['service']))
 {
   $json = json_decode($_POST['service'], true);

   echo $json["service"]["name"] . "<br />";

   foreach ($json["service"]["sizeTypes"] as $key => $value){
     echo $value["value"] . "<br />";
   }
 }
 else
 {
   echo "Nooooooob";
 }
 ?>
```

I do not have the UPDATE query in place yet because I am not even sure if I am passing the JSON correctly.  In the javascript click function, you see the SUCCESS and ERROR functions.  All I am producing is the ERROR function in Chrome's console.

I am not sure where the error lies, in the JavaScript or the PHP.

Why can I only produce the error function in the AJAX post?

### Edit

I removed the dataType in the ajax call, and added JSON.stringify to data:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'api/editService.php',
   data: {servce: JSON.stringify(payload)},
   success: function(msg){
     console.log('success');
   },
   error: function(msg){
     console.log('fail'), msg);
   }
 });
```

In the PHP script, I tried this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['service'))
 {
   $json = json_decode($_POST['service'], true);

   foreach ($json["service"]["sizeTypes"] as $key => $value){
     $insert = mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO table (COLUMN, COLUMN, COLUMN) VALUES (".$json["service"] . ", " . "$value["id"] . ", " . $value["value"]")");
   }
 }
 else
 {
   echo "noooooob";
 }
```

With this update, I am able to get the success message to fire, but that's pretty much it.  I cannot get the query to run.

Comment: You might want to log `msg` instead of `'fail'`.

Comment: I.e.: `console.log('fail:', msg);`

Comment: And there is no reason to use `json_decode()` in your PHP, the `$_POST` variable will not contain json.

Comment: @MarcoS - doing what you requested, this is what the console returned:  fail Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵↵<br>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: I posted an answer, the error might be that you are echoing html but ajax is expecting json (dataType: 'json')

Comment: @HoodCoderMan You're getting error may be because of this line. echo $json["service"]["name"]. You don't have any name key in the given example array string.

Comment: @HoodCoderMan Also you don't need to do json_decode as you're passing value as object only.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments.  They have been helpful.  I am testing all of your suggestions.  Upvotes to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

without seeing the error, I suspect the error is because ajax is expecting json (dataType: 'json',) but you are echoing html in your php

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
 error: function(msg){
   console.log('fail');
 }
```

to

```
 error: function(msg){
   console.log(msg);
 }
```

There might be some php error or syntax issue and you should be able to see it there.

Also try to debug your php script step by step by adding something like

`echo "still works";die;`

on the beginning of php script and moving it down till it'll cause error, then you'll know where the error is.

Also if you're expecting JSON (and you are - `dataType: 'json'` in js , don't echo any HTML in your php.

Comment: I changed the error function as suggested, and I got the below console message: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}  I also removed the HTML tags from the PHP script

Answer (score 1):

As you are sending an object in your `service` key, you probably have a multi-dimensional array in `$_POST['service']`.

If you want to send a string, you should convert the object to json:

```
data: {service: JSON.stringify(payload)},
```

Now you can decode it like you are doing in php.

Also note that you can only send json back from php if you set the `dataType` to `json`. Anything other than valid json will have you end up in the `error` handler.

Comment: You don't need to do that with jQuery if you're setting it to json. You can pass js object and have php array on back-end

Comment: ^depend on jquery version I guess, no?

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak I'm pretty sure you do, otherwise you end up with values like `$_POST['service']['sizeTypes'][..]`, which is also perfectly valid and common when you use arrays in your `name` attributes of the form inputs. So the OP probably doesn't even have to decode the current value :-)

Answer (score 0):

Example how to handle a `JSON` response from `editService.php`. Typically, the `editService.php` script will be the *worker* and will handle whatever it is you need done. It will (typically) send a simple response *back* to the `success` method (consider updating your `$.ajax` to use the latest methods, eg. `$.done`, etc). From there you handle the responses appropriately.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/editService.php',
    data: { service: payload },
    dataType: 'json'
})
 .done(function(msh) {
    if (msh.success) {
        console.log('success');
    }
    else {
        console.log('failed');
    }
})
 .fail(function(msg) {
    console.log('fail');
});
```

Example `/editService.php` and how to work with `JSON` via `$.ajax`

```
<?php
$response = [];
if ( isset($_POST['service']) ) {
    // do your stuff; DO NOT output (echo) anything here, this is simply logic
    // ... do some more stuff

    // if everything has satisfied, send response back
    $response['success'] = true;

    // else, if this logic fails, send that response back
    $response['success'] = false;
}
else {
    // initial condition failed
    $response['success'] = false;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```